# Not allowed to load local resource: angular js spring

Tags: angularjs, spring

I'm using angular js in front and and spring boot in backend. I succeeded to upload image to my database and to put it in a local folder. My problem when i want to display this image using ng-src angular js i get this error :

```
Not allowed to load local resource: C:/Users/Public/Pictures/5ecece06-5306-4743-a003-1590e202a000-original.jpeg
```

i put the images into public folder the same error i got it.
this my webservice :

```
kioskHotelCode: "ABRH",
```

countryName: "test test",
url: null,
hotelImage: "C:/Users/Public/Pictures/5ecece06-5306-4743-a003-1590e202a000-original.jpeg",

also i tried to add  file:///:

```
<img alt="here should be an image"
```

ng-src="file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/5ecece06-5306-4743-a003-1590e202a000-original.jpeg" width="100"height="90">

this is also my web service in backend:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sid", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage() throws IOException {

    ClassPathResource imgFile = new ClassPathResource(uploadsDir);
    byte[] bytes = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(imgFile.getInputStream());

    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG).body(bytes);
}
```

but it 's the same error, i'm testing with google chrome and i don't find a solution. my questions which the best way to solve this problem? and where i should put the image that are dynamic(i mean user can change it )?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your image in context path of that Spring webapp and retrieve it from that location.

If image is in: 
`WEB-INF/IMG/image.jpg`

You can retrieve it as: 
`IMG/image.jpg`

If you want to make it dynamic the same location will work

Answer (score 0):

you should not use local image, cause when you publish your application other browsers clients can not see this images.
try this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources